# Windows folder access working with share path but not using absolute path

Tags: windows, path

I am trying to use the `net use` command to get access to a directory on another server. It works fine when using share path (`net use \\server\sharefolder`) but not when using the absolute path (`net use \\server\c$\sharefolder`).

I am getting the following error in the second case:

```
System error 5 has occurred.

Access is denied.
```

The folder is in C drive on the server and the user being used has full access to the folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C$ Windows shares are hidden shares and not for general use. You need to be an administrator of the server as well as the workstation.

It is truly best for most environments not to use C$ shares in normal use.  The C$ practice pretty much ended with Windows XP and old servers.

Set up the shares on the domain and provide permissions with Organization groups in Active Directory. This will work very well for you.

Also no need whatever to make registry changes.

Answer (score 0):

To get rid of the Access Denied message, follow this procedure:

- Run `regedit`
- Navigate to
  `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System`
- Create a new entry by right-clicking System and then selecting "DWORD (32-bit) Value"
- Set `LocalAccountTokenFilterPolicy` as name for the new entry
- Set the value of `LocalAccountTokenFilterPolicy` to `1` by right-click.

Comment: thanks for the answer. Can you please let me know what adding this entry will do (other than possibly fixing my issue)? Also, I would really prefer not having to change the registry to fix this issue

Comment: It disables a security feature. See: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/windows-security/user-account-control-and-remote-restriction  
`When a user who is a member of the local administrators group on the target remote computer establishes a remote administrative connection by using the net use *\\remotecomputer\Share$ command, for example, they will not connect as a full administrator. The user has no elevation potential on the remote computer, and the user cannot perform administrative tasks`

Comment: thanks @pwnosh. The article also mentions that if you are using a domain user account, this won't be an issue. I am using a domain user account for this